The year is coming to an end or the end?
It occurred to me today (December 31st) that the year is coming to an
end. Not the end? Isn’t there one end of the year?

You can say either. [Coming to/reaching/arriving at] 'an end' is a fixed idiom and is used even when there is obviously only one end of something.

Or "to its end".

"an end" because we don't  know quite yet how it will end.  It's like a long story and we're near the final pages.  What the end will be is still indefinite while it is "coming".

It's more common to use "the end" when it's followed by "of something", e.g. "It's the end of the year."

There are at least a couple of reasons why "the year is coming to an end" is the idiomatic choice.
Firstly, "an end" better describes to the process or generality of something concluding, rather than pointing to a specific, singular conclusion. You can speak about the whole month of December being "the end of the year", but you could also say that about the last day of December. "Coming to an end" is an indeterminate period of time.
Secondly, "the end", being a specific point, requires a bit more detail. You can say something is happening "at the end of the year", but if you say the year itself has come to "the end", it sounds like information is missing. The end of what? The end of the year. But you can't say "the year has come to the end of the year".
